# Is it possible to write good Code (create a good code framework) AND use Cucumber (or another Gherkin tool)?

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, best-practices

When I look at the code Cucumber outputs, it does not seem to follow best practices (or any moderately good practices) for writing a testing framework.

Question: Is there a way to use Cucumber and still have a good framework for the code behind Cucumber?

I am guessing the answer is no, but if anyone if anyone can point me to some articles on the subject matter that would be great. I'm probably googling the wrong term and not finding any articles concerning this question. Thanks.

Comment: You should be more precise. First check this [book](https://sukesh15.gitbooks.io/cucumber-jvm-test-framework-/content/bdd_-_the_basics/), and then tell me what is wrong with that approach (and we can go from here)

Comment: Yes.  However the question is too broad.  Cucumber output is whatever english you put in, it is not the code which is called.

Comment: Cucumber is just a BDD tool to add to an existing framework.  Like any tool, it can be added to well-designed/written frameworks as well as not-so-well-designed/written frameworks.  Can you show an example of why you singled-out Gherkin tools in particular regarding "best practices?"  I'm not saying you're wrong, I just would like clarity in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the input. I was not sure how cucumber hooked up to the code. Therefore, I was not sure if the Framework was created by cucumber. I would hear the phrase, "this code was generated by cucumber" and then look at the code and the code was not structured well at all. I was trying to figure out if the unusual framework was because they were using Cucumber, or because the developer decided to organize stuff this way. Thanks so much for all the help.